# How to do $arcsin(1/2)$ by hand?

Tags: calculus

Can I get help on how I can calculate this without a calculator? I know it's the inverse of $sin(1/2)$, but I'm still a little confused on how I get $\pi / 2$ from this.

Thanks!

Comment: But $sin \pi/2$ is $1,$ not $1/2.$

Comment: Draw a triangle and use the definition of the sine function.

Comment: When you say the inverse of $\sin(1/2)$, are you implying that $\arcsin(1/2) = 1/\sin(1/2)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I think a functional inverse was intended, not a reciprocal.

Comment: That's right @J.G.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an equilateral triangle if side length $2$. An altitude cuts one of the $\pi/3$ angles into two copies of $\pi/6$, in hypotenuse-$2$ right-angled triangles with opposite $1$. Thus $\pi/6=\arcsin 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin30^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2}$ and for all $-1\leq x\leq 1$ we have $-90^{\circ}\leq\arcsin x\leq90^{\circ}.$

Thus, $\arcsin\frac{1}{2}=30^{\circ}.$